# Distinguish between CANCELLED and NOANSWERED calls in asterisk 11

Tags: asterisk, voip, elastix, cdr

I have configured Asterisk CDR system to log cdr records in the database (using Elastix 2.5). Now I want to determine which call was cancelled by the caller and which one was not answered by the callee. I have seen in the [Asterisk CDR Wiki page](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+12+CDR+Specification) that CDR system is considering both 'Cancel' and 'NoAnswer' calls as 'NoAnswer'.
Is there any solution to change this setting?

I have also tried to use DIALSTATUS channel variable to solve this problem and import the value of this variable to the database using CDR function, but unfortunately the result wasn't desirable!
Is there any way to do this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If A call B then A is CALLER, B is CALLED.

CANCELED call are calls which hanguped by CALLER **before CALLED party answer**.

NOANSWER call are calls which ended by Dial command timeout or other timeout(like provider's max call time at their end).

If call hanguped by CALLER or CALLED **AFTER** answer, state will be ANSWERED.

No, you have no way change this.

Comment: Thank you @arheops. I know the difference between them and I want to distinguish between CANCELED and NOANSWER calls. Is there any solution for this?